# Spanish Language not showing in magento 1.9

Tags: store-view, language, magento-1.9.3.2

I have the Spanish language on my website.A few days back it is working fine.Suddenly both the frontend and backend were displaying in English.
I have only one store in this language.

In the backend only the time is showing in spanish language.

> jueves, 18 de enero de 2018

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you install any third party extension lastly? Or make any changes into website?

Comment: Hai @DhirenVasoya, I didn't install any third party package or changed anything in the website.Deleted var ,cleared cache,reindex.Everything is done.No luck

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it myself.Actually the csv files aren't saved in a correct format. After saving the csv files in correct utf-8 format.Translation is working